# checking if the user marked the js answer

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple quiz with questions and I have a dilemma how to write code. Namely, I want to write a function that would check for me if the user marked a given answer.

So I assume the user knows the answer to the question and marks that answer. So I make myself a variable called `const isChecked` and which stores me a boolean `true` value because I assume the user selects the answer to a given question.

However, if for some reason it does not select the question because, for example, it does not know the answer to it, this variable now stores the logical value of `false` and the function that is responsible for displaying subsequent questions will not be run when the user tries to click the send button.

I have such a concept. I create a variable that holds me true. Let this variable be named `isChecked`:

```
const isChecked = true;
```

Because as I said, I assume that the user knows the answer to a given question and wants to move on. Therefore, the condition is met. So if

```
if (isChecked === true) {
  // the code will be executed because the user marked the answer
}
```

However, if the user does not know the answer to the question, the variable isChecked holds the value `false`; `const isChecked = false`. Therefore, if fails to execute, it will be `false`, but the else will be executed:

```
if (isChecked === true) {
  // the code will not execute because the user has not selected the answer
} else {
  // the code will execute because the value is true. And at this point I want to block the user from going to the next question when trying to press the send button.
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aplikacja quizu</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="aplikacja, quiz, pytania, odpowiedzi">
    <meta name="description" content="Podstawowa aplikacja do quizu">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-quiz">
            <div class="content-quiz-questions">
                <h2 id="header-questions"></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="content-quiz-answers">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_a" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="a" for="answer_a"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_b" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="b" for="answer_b"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_c" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="c" for="answer_c"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_d" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="d" for="answer_d"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is all my code so far:

```js
let oldQuestionIndex = -1;

const headerQuestions = document.getElementById('header-questions');

const answerA = document.getElementById('a');
const answerB = document.getElementById('b');
const answerC = document.getElementById('c');
const answerD = document.getElementById('d');

let arrAnswerVaranty = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];

const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('.btn-submit');

const quizArr = [
    {
        question: 'What is the most used programming language in 2019?',
        answers: [ 'Java', 'C', 'Python', 'JS' ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Who is the President of US?',
        answers: [ 'Florin Pop', 'Joe Biden', 'Ivan Saldano', 'Mihai Andrei' ]
    },
    {
        question: 'What does HTML stand for?',
        answers: [
            'Hypertext Markup Language',
            'Cascading Style Sheet',
            'Jason Object Notation',
            'Helicopters Terminals Motorboats Lamborgini'
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'What year was JavaScript launched?',
        answers: [ '1996', '1995', '1994', 'none of the above' ]
    }
];

function showAnswersQuiz(answers) {
    for (const id in quizArr) {
        document.getElementById(arrAnswerVaranty[id]).innerHTML = answers[id];
    }
}

function showRandomQuestions() {
    do {
        var randomQuestIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quizArr.length);
    } while (randomQuestIndex === oldQuestionIndex);
    oldQuestionIndex = randomQuestIndex;
    headerQuestions.innerHTML = quizArr[randomQuestIndex].question;
    showAnswersQuiz(quizArr[randomQuestIndex].answers);
}

function isValid() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrAnswerVaranty.length; i++) {
        if (!arrAnswerVaranty[i].checked) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
isValid()
btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    showRandomQuestions();
});
showRandomQuestions();
```

The function it writes for the problem described above is called `checkIfChecked`. I just wanted to know if this is the right concept or do you have a better one?

Comment: do you have the html part as well?

Comment: Yes of course, yes

Comment: @P.Ba I think what @ Nina Scholz says is you should include the html in this post, aka [mcve]

Comment: Yes. Already done.

Answer (score 0):

1. const variables can't change their value once initialized;
2. here is function if you use checkbox for user to check answer

```js
function ischecked(checkbox){
  if(checkbox.checked == true){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}

ischecked(document.getElementsByClassName('answer1')[0]); //call example (use it as a value for bool variable)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="answer1">
```

Or if user click buttons to to answer:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("answer1")[0].addEventListener('click', logthevalue); // could be replaced by 'onclick' event in html object, for ex. onclick="logthevalue(this)"

var checkedarray = [];

ischecked(document.getElementsByClassName("answer1")[0]); //call example, returns bool value

function logthevalue(button){
  if (checkedarray.indexOf(button) == -1){
    checkedarray.push(button);
  }
  else{
    checkedarray.splice(checkedarray.indexOf(button), 1);
  }
}

function ischecked(button){
  if (checkedarray.indexOf(button) != -1){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="answer1">JabaScrupt</button>
```

Comment: I started writing this code
```js
function isValid() {
for (let i = 0; i < arrAnswerVaranty.length; i++) {
if (arrAnswerVaranty[i].cheked === false) {
}else{
}
}
}
```
I just don't know what I should write in the body of if and else statements to be able to react appropriately if the user selects or does not select this answer

Comment: please don't use the pattern `if (someBoolean == true)`, because the variavle with a boolean value is enough for the if statement.

Comment: My point is, how can I block a user from going to the next question if the condition is there
let isChecked = false
if (isChecked.checked === false) {
what to enter here?
}

Comment: @P.Ba add return statements   if (arrAnswerVaranty[i].cheked === false)  {return false;} else {return true;}

Comment: @P.Ba after that just use function as a value for variable 
for ex. var some = isValid();

Comment: Did not work. When the user clicks the send button and does not select any answer, he can proceed to the next question. This is not what I mean. Does not select the answer, clicks the send button and does not go to the next question. Highlight the answer and click the button can move on

Comment: @P.Ba could you add isValid() function to the first post, so i may fully understand

Answer (score 0):

The submit button is disabled until a radio button is clicked and when submit is clicked un-checks all the radios for the next question. I have added comments in code for better understanding.

```js
let oldQuestionIndex = -1;
const headerQuestions = document.getElementById('header-questions');

const answerA = document.getElementById('a');
const answerB = document.getElementById('b');
const answerC = document.getElementById('c');
const answerD = document.getElementById('d');

const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('.btn-submit');

const quizArr = [
  {
    question: 'What is the most used programming language in 2019?',
    answers: [ 'Java', 'C', 'Python', 'JS' ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Who is the President of US?',
    answers: [ 'Florin Pop', 'Joe Biden', 'Ivan Saldano', 'Mihai Andrei' ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What does HTML stand for?',
    answers: [
      'Hypertext Markup Language',
      'Cascading Style Sheet',
      'Jason Object Notation',
      'Helicopters Terminals Motorboats Lamborgini'
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What year was JavaScript launched?',
    answers: [ '1996', '1995', '1994', 'none of the above' ]
  }
];

function showAnswersQuiz(answers) {
    let arrAnswerVaranty = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ];
    for (const id in quizArr) {
        document.getElementById(arrAnswerVaranty[id]).innerHTML = answers[id];
    }

    const radioArr = document.getElementsByClassName('answer');
    
    //add change event on radio buttons and when one is clicked enable submit 
    for(let i=0;i<radioArr.length;i++){
        radioArr[i].addEventListener('change', radioChanged);
    }
    
    btnSubmit.disabled = true;
}

function radioChanged(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
    checkIfChecked(true);
}

function showRandomQuestions() {
  var randomQuestIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quizArr.length);
  headerQuestions.innerHTML = quizArr[randomQuestIndex].question;
  showAnswersQuiz(quizArr[randomQuestIndex].answers);
}

function checkIfChecked(isChecked) {
  if (isChecked) {
    btnSubmit.disabled = false;
  } else {
    btnSubmit.disabled = true;
  }
}

btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //reset all the radio buttons on submit for the next question
    const radioArr = document.getElementsByClassName('answer');
    for(let i=0;i<radioArr.length;i++){
        radioArr[i].checked = false;
    }
    showRandomQuestions();
});


showRandomQuestions();
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div class="content-quiz">
            <div class="content-quiz-questions">
                <h2 id="header-questions"></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="content-quiz-answers">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_a" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="a" for="answer_a"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_b" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="b" for="answer_b"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_c" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="c" for="answer_c"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="answer_d" name="answer" class="answer">
                        <label id="d" for="answer_d"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ok, your code is working. But isn't it possible to take advantage of it?
```js
function isValid() {
 for (let i = 0; i < arrAnswerVaranty.length; i++) {
  if (!arrAnswerVaranty[i].checked) {
   return false;
  } else {
   return true;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: @P.Ba When the `isValid()` is called?

Comment: It just still doesn't work. Do not put your code in because I am asking you for tips, not for a ready-made one

Comment: @P.Ba Look you must call the function in order to enable/disable the submit button. And the only way is when you click on a radio button.

Comment: Where exactly should I call this function?

Comment: @P.Ba on change event of radio button. It signals that at least one radio is checked and you enable the submit

Answer (score 0):

So if I correctly understand the question here, you want to write a function that checks if there is a selected answer (at least one radio checked).

That would as simple as below. I also added a useful "reset" as a bonus ;)

Using the `:checked` selector, `document.querySelector("[name='answer']:checked")` will return `null` or the checked element. The `!!` (not not) operator will turn it into a boolean.

```js
const btnSubmit = document.querySelector(".btn-submit");

// Returns a boolean to know if at least a radio is checked
function isValid(){
  return !!document.querySelector("[name='answer']:checked");
}

// Resets all radios
function clear(){
  document.querySelectorAll("[name='answer']").forEach(function(radio){
    radio.checked = false;
  })
}

// "submit" button click handler
btnSubmit.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log(isValid())
  clear()
})
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-quiz">
    <div class="content-quiz-questions">
      <h2 id="header-questions"></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-quiz-answers">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="answer_a" name="answer" class="answer">
          <label id="a" for="answer_a">A</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="answer_b" name="answer" class="answer">
          <label id="b" for="answer_b">B</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="answer_c" name="answer" class="answer">
          <label id="c" for="answer_c">C</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="radio" id="answer_d" name="answer" class="answer">
          <label id="d" for="answer_d">D</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```